# delete multiple values in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am using xampp(phpmyadmin) for database I have two tables one is registration1 with fields(sn,firstname,faculty,semester,batch) and other is course with fields(sn,course). SN in registration1 is primary key and SN in course is foreign key reference to registration1. Now I want to delete all the data from course table based on faculty and semester. 
I use the following code but there is an error:

```
DELETE FROM registration1 as r,course as c 
    WHERE r.SN = c.SN and r.Faculty="BBA" and r.Semester = "2nd";
```

How do I delete the data from course table?

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete all the data from course table based on faculty and semester.

```
DELETE FROM course
WHERE SN IN (SELECT SN 
             FROM registration1 
             WHERE Faculty="BBA" AND Semester = "2nd")
```